# are my fonts embedded?

Tags: fonts, pdf

tried to submit my thesis to my school. However they told me that my fonts were not embedded, which they need for archival purposes. I thought I took the necessary steps to make sure they were. I think my .pdf figures in the document are likely the culprit....

But they're telling me that it's because in adobe document viewer there are fonts that say "Embedded" instead of "Embedded Subset". They say this means the fonts are not actually embedded. Are they correct?

I'm surprised how much trouble I'm finding online on if a font labeled as "Embedded" really is embedded or not. From my reading I feel like Embedded is everything Embedded Subset is and then some (the characters not used in the pdf).

[image: screenshot of document properties]

Comment: Which engine are you using to compile? The way fonts are handled depends on the engine used. I'm guessing the answer is either XeTeX or LuaTeX, though pdfTeX is also possible. Although the Arial fonts you show *are* embedded, complete embedding can be problematic. (On the other hand, subsetting isn't possible in all cases.) This isn't just the licence issue rallig mentions, but also the technical one of potential clashes. So the answer is that 'yes, these particular fonts are embedded' but 'no, that doesn't mean it's OK'.

Comment: Doing the steps provided in this link seemed to help with my problem. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/My_submission_was_rejected_by_the_journal_because_%22Font_XYZ_is_not_embedded%22._What_can_I_do%3F

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue has been resolved using instructions available on Overleaf (see comments) and sufficient information was never provided to diagnose the problem, let alone resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

It is very rare to embed an entire font. I was not aware that TeX could do it, without hacking.

Does your document contain other PDF files, placed as pages or images? Some validation software does not detect a font that is "embedded in the contained page" as being "embedded in the entire document."

One possibility: Can you print the finished PDF to another PDF file? (Not using TeX software.) That might dis-entangle how fonts are embedded.

But as for your original question: I think that they are wrong. If the viewer says that the fonts are embedded, and the PDF displays without error, then the fonts are embedded (or subset embedded). But many fonts (including Arial) are licensed in a way that prohibits embedding the entire font. You are only allowed to embed the characters that are actually used. Perhaps that is what they detected, but they did not explain it correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't call editing a configuration file 'hacking'. Whether to embed a font at all and, if so, whether to subset it is configurable by design.

Comment: Thank you, this reply is very thorough. I am doing something in my latex compilation to make sure my fonts are embedded

I took that out, and the fonts that are embedded are all now "embedded subset" . However, a few remain that are not embedded at all. So, I use adobe acrobat to save as a PDF/a and that helps to get those fonts embedded. But it also makes a few other fonts that originally "Embedded Subset " go to "Embedded", which is what my school wants me to avoid....

Comment: Also, here's the documentation I followed from overleaf to Embed my fonts. This step is how my fonts were showing up as "Embedded"

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/My_submission_was_rejected_by_the_journal_because_%22Font_XYZ_is_not_embedded%22._What_can_I_do%3F

Comment: @cfr Although editing a configuration file is rather low-level "hacking" it may be the case that OP is restricted to using TeX as-is, on a university computer that limits what a user can do. I suppose that *.cfg could be placed in the document directory, though.

Comment: Is Adobe Acrobat Pro (not just Reader) available at your school, somewhere? Might be part of Adobe Creative Suite, nowadys, although it was once a separate program. If anyone there has it, most likely places would be the publication offices (whoever prepares catalogs, etc.). Acrobat Pro can get down into the details of PDF structure. But it sounds as if your revised PDF is OK.

Comment: @AliasNyquist So do you have images which don't have embedded fonts? Are they the source of the problem? If so and if you can, I'd try to fix those outside Overleaf individually. At the very least, it'll give you a better idea of where the problem is. Also, can you add the font configuration of your document to your question and let us know which engine you're using? (OverLeaf offers several - I think pdfTeX is default.) And the output of `pdffonts` on the PDF would be good, if you can manage it.